# capitalize every other letter in a string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, function

This is my code:

```
def mock(s):
    ret = ""
    i = True  
    for char in s:
        if i:
            ret += char.upper()
        else:
            ret += char.lower()
        if char != ' ':
            i = not i
    return ret
print(mock("abcd efgh ijkl"))
```

output:

```
AbCd EfGh IjKl
```

but it has to be like this:

```
AbCd eFgH IjKl
```

I don't get what i'm doing wrong and what I should do to fix it.

Comment: @RyanHaining Because there is a if check that prevents the thing he wants to do (`if char != ' ':`)

Comment: @MegaIng It looks like she's just misunderstood spaces, I don't look at that as convincing that OP didn't write this.

Comment: Looks like this is about [the "mocking spongebob" problem](https://dmoj.ca/problem/mockingspongebob). In that case OP should have provided examples with multiple spaces, or other non-alphabetic characters like `"abc      de'fg..h"` which should result in `"aBc      De'Fg..H"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def mock(s):
    ret = ""
    i = True  
    for char in s:
        if i:
            ret += char.upper()
        else:
            ret += char.lower()

        i = not i

    return ret
print(mock("abcd efgh ijkl"))
```

Outputs:

```
AbCd eFgH IjKl
```

The expected output does not care about spaces

Answer (score 3):

You could use a simple comprehension and `join()`:

```
s = 'abcd efgh ijkl'
morph = ''.join([e.upper() if i%2==0 else e for i, e in enumerate(s)])
print(morph)
```

Output:

```
AbCd eFgH IjKl
```

Note that this does not *technically* capitalize every other letter (unless you consider spaces to be letters), but instead capitalizes every other index, which it seems is what you want based on your desired output.

To fix your current code, all you would need to do is replace:

```
if char != ' ':
    i = not i
```

With:

```
i = not i
```