# Upper case characters every other character but ignoring symbols and spaces

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a novice working on a practice script of which I have 90% figured out but am stumped on one portion. I'm doing the [mocking spongebob "challenge"](https://dmoj.ca/problem/mockingspongebob) on dmoj which asks you to make every other character of a given string upper case, but demands symbols and spaces to be ignored and only letters to be counted.

I and am able to make every other character upper case or lower case, but I am not sure how to ignore symbols and spaces? I'll drop what I have so far for critique. Thank you for your time.

```
meme1 = "I don't even know her like that"
meme2 = "You can't just make a new meme from a different Spongebob clip every 
couple of months"
meme3 = "I must have listened to that latest Ed Sheeran song 10000 times!"

memeFIN1 = [""] * len(meme1)
memeFIN2 = [""] * len(meme2)
memeFIN3 = [""] * len(meme3)

memeFIN1[1::2] = meme1[1::2].upper()
memeFIN2[1::2] = meme2[1::2].upper()
memeFIN3[1::2] = meme3[1::2].upper()

memeFIN1[::2] = meme1[::2].lower()
memeFIN2[::2] = meme2[::2].lower()
memeFIN3[::2] = meme3[::2].lower()

memeFIN1 = "".join(memeFIN1)
memeFIN2 = "".join(memeFIN2)
memeFIN3 = "".join(memeFIN3)

print(memeFIN1)
print(memeFIN2)
print(memeFIN3)
```

EDIT:
<s>All of the following solutions in the answers helped me come to my own, but none of them seemed to work entirely on their own.</s> In cheesits solution, changing counter to start at 1 works, but not realizing that (as an utter noob) I did counters differently, essentially doing the same thing. This is the solution that worked for me:

```
meme1 = "I don't even know her like that"
meme2 = "You can't just make a new meme from a different Spongebob clip every couple of months"
meme3 = "I must have listened to that latest Ed Sheeran song 10000 times!"

def spongebobify(meme):
    count = 0
    char = []

    for ch in meme:
        if ch.isalpha() and count % 2 == 1:
            char.append(ch.upper())
            count += 1
        elif ch.isalpha():
            char.append(ch.lower())
            count += 1
        else:
            char.append(ch)

    return ''.join(char)

m1 = spongebobify(meme1)
m2 = spongebobify(meme2)
m3 = spongebobify(meme3)

print (m1)
print (m2)
print (m3)
```

Comment: `upper()` doesn't do anything to symbols and spaces, you don't need to do anything special to ignore them.

Comment: @Barmar He does for the sake of skipping over them, like "Hi. I'm SpOnGeBoB."

Comment: You can't use a slice for this. You need to write a loop or list comprehension, so you can increment the counter only when the character is a letter.

Comment: @Barmar That was my thought, issue uniformly "every other lettter" isn't capitalized because the symbols are not ignored if you catch my meaning.

Comment: also @Barmar thank you I will give a for loop a shot instead

Comment: [popular question today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49928375)

Comment: @TheSnydaMan all of the solutions posted below work.  It is misleading to say "none of them seemed to work" when that's not true

Comment: @JayFresco , I did not mean this as a slight in any way, but when I used their code none of the solutions at the times did _exactly_ what they had to do. Most didnt actually skip spaces if I recall, but it was always some small thing. They all did like, 95% of what I needed to do, and pulling things from a few of them worked 100%.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want something readable, try this:

```
def spongebobify(phrase):

    ## Turn every character lowercase
    phrase = phrase.lower()

    ## Keep track of how many letters you've seen
    counter = 0

    ## Create a list to hold characters
    chars = []

    ## Go through the entire string
    for ch in phrase:

        ## If this is a letter, increment
        if ch.isalpha():
            counter += 1

        ## If this is a letter and our counter is odd:
        if ch.isalpha() and counter % 2:
            chars.append(ch.upper())

        ## Otherwise, just add it as-is
        else:
            chars.append(ch)

    return ''.join(chars)
```

If you want a one liner (disregarding efficiency):

```
def spongebobify(phrase):
    return ''.join([ch.lower() if ch.isalpha() and len([c for c in phrase[:i] if c.isalpha()]) % 2 else ch for i, ch in enumerate(phrase.upper())])

    ## Readable version:
    #return ''.join([
    #    ch.lower()
    #    if ch.isalpha()
    #    and len([c for c in phrase[:i] if c.isalpha()]) % 2
    #    else ch
    #    for i, ch in enumerate(phrase.upper())
    #])
```

Comment: This helped me come to a solution quite a bit, thank you! That being said, this doesn't resolve it quite properly on it's own. The majority worked but the issue was in the way count was working with two "if"s as opposed to an if, followed by an elif. I edited the fully functioning code to my main post. The vast majority is build off of yours, thank you!

Comment: @TheSnydaMan this version works perfectly.  If you want the sequence to start with a lowercase letter then you can toggle `counter = 1` instead of `counter = 0`

Comment: @JayFresco, right, I am a total noob and this was actually my first real Python exercise at all, and I didnt think about turning count to one. This led me to thinking this one just didn't work the way I needed it too, when It only needed a super small modification. I see now that the way I handled adding counters just did the same thing as changing the initial variable to one in the first place. This solution is essentially the one I went with.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a bit to indicate which lower/upper you're currently looking at, toggling the bit whenever an alpha character is found.

```
def speak_like_spongebob(phrase):
    case_bit = 0
    res = []
    for lower_upper in zip(phrase.lower(), phrase.upper()):
        res.append(lower_upper[case_bit])
        case_bit ^= lower_upper[0].isalpha()
    return ''.join(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a loop, so you can increment a counter only when the character is a letter, and then check whether that counter is odd or even.

```
def mock_spongebob(input):
    letters = 0
    result = ""
    for c in input:
        if c.isalpha():
            result += c.lower() if letters % 2 == 0 else c.upper()
            letters += 1
        else:
            result += c
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you will need to iterate through each character in the strings, determine whether it's a character or a symbol, and act accordingly.

The following program would print every other character in uppercase, not counting non-alphabetic characters:

```
meme1 = "I don't even know her like that"
meme2 = "You can't just make a new meme from a different Spongebob clip every couple of months"
meme3 = "I must have listened to that latest Ed Sheeran song 10000 times!"

for meme in [meme1, meme2, meme3]:
    count = 0
    meme_mod = ""
    for c in meme:
        if not c.isalpha():
            meme_mod += c
            continue
        elif count % 2 == 0:
            meme_mod += c.lower()
        else:
            meme_mod += c.upper()
        count += 1
    print meme_mod
```

This program would output:

```
i DoN't EvEn KnOw HeR lIkE tHaT
yOu CaN't JuSt MaKe A nEw MeMe FrOm A dIfFeReNt SpOnGeBoB cLiP eVeRy CoUpLe Of MoNtHs
i MuSt HaVe LiStEnEd To ThAt LaTeSt Ed ShEeRaN sOnG 10000 tImEs!
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an [article](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-write-a-spongebob-mocking-converter-in-python-cbccae720f8f) that shows how to write a SpongeBob Mocking Converter script in Python